# Get the clicked object that triggered jquery blur() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, onblur

Suppose I do this:

```
$(target).blur(function(e){
  //do stuff
});
```

Is there a way to fetch the object that was clicked on in order to trigger the blur action?

I tried using `e.target`, but that appears to be returning the object attached to the blur action rather than the clicked object.

Comment: Why is this question marked as a duplicate? I haven't found another question specifically about jQuery's blur event. If it really is a dupe, please link to the duplicate question.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to make non-Chromium browsers work in this situation? Tabbing outside of the field cannot be handled in order to get the new focused element, as far as I can tell. `var target = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;` returns nothing. Crappy specs from crappy spec writers...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it:

```
$(function() {

    var clicky;

    $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        // The latest element clicked
        clicky = $(e.target);
    });

    // when 'clicky == null' on blur, we know it was not caused by a click
    // but maybe by pressing the tab key
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        clicky = null;
    });

    $(target).blur(function(e) {
        console.log(clicky);
    });​​

});
```

Answer (score 49):

The trick is to wait an extra tick:

```
$(el).blur(function (event) {
    // If we just hangout an extra tick, we'll find out which element got focus really
    setTimeout(function(){
       document.activeElement; // This is the element that has focus
    },1);
})
```

Comment: I found that `setTimeout` needed an explicit delay to allow the other `click` event to fire; also for me (jQuery 1.8) `document.activeElement` was `body`, which wasn't very helpful :)

Comment: I should add there might be better ways of doing this, all along the same lines, by using `setImmediate` or `requestAnimationFrame`

Answer (score 7):

Inside an event handler, `this` will be the element the event is bound to, and `e.target` will be the element that triggered the event (may or not be the same as `this`).

You are handing a `blur` event, not a `click` event.  So, inside your event, you will have the element that you `blur`ed.  If you want the `click`ed element, you'd need another event to get that.

`blur` can be triggered by other events, such as focusing something; not just clicking on something.  So, there is no way to get the element that "caused the blur".

Comment: It's not true that there's no way. Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11544589/1450294

Comment: This is easily achievable in Flash/AS3, with the FocusIn and FocusOut events, which include the objects receiving and losing the focus, with simple ability to cancel.  Nice to see that in 2018, JavaScript/HTML is now over a decade behind Flash with no easy way to do this.  I hate posting comments like this, but the sheer superiority of the AS3 language over JS becomes more and more irritating the longer I watch JS remain terrible and lacking, year after year.

Answer (score 1):

Using this within `blur` handler function will give you the blurred element.

```
$(target).blur(function(e){
   var blurredElement = this;  // dom element
   // To make a jQuery object 
   var blurredElement = $(this);
});
```

Within `blur` event you can't catch the clicked element. To get the `click`ed element you need `click` event. For example:

```
$(element).click(function() {
  var clickedElement = this;
});
```

And to get the focused element you can use `:focus` selector like: `$(':focus')` will returns you focused element in document.

Comment: I found that I needed to put `$someElement.is(':focus')` or `$(':focus')` within a `setTimeout` function, triggered by the blur handler, to give some browsers a chance to focus on the next element.