# How can determine which DOM object was clicked/focused with jQuery and blur event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, blur

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#mylink" tabindex="-1">select this</a>
    <a href="#mylink" tabindex="-1">select this</a>
    <a href="#mylink" tabindex="-1">select this</a>
</div>

<a href="#begin" tabindex="-1">click here to begin selecting</a>
```

And I have this JS/jQuery snippet of code:

```
$('a[href="#begin"]').blur(function(e) {
    console.log( e.target.href ); // this will output: #begin
});
```

So what I need with `.blur` is to determine which element got focus after the `<a href="#begin">` was blured.

Is this possible with JS/jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the clicked object that triggered jquery blur() event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544554/get-the-clicked-object-that-triggered-jquery-blur-event)

Answer (score 1):

You can check which element gets focus by using the [`.focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) method, similar to `.blur`

During your blur event, you can set a flag to "look out" for the next control focus. In your focus function, if this flag is set then you know your "being" field was the last one to lose focus. You will also need to reset the flag when any other field is blurred though.

Here is a simple concept example...

```
var beginWasLast = false;

$('a[href="#begin"]').blur(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    beginWasLast = true;
    console.log( e.target.href ); // this will output: #begin
});

$('a[href="#begin"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('a:not(a[href="#begin"])').blur(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    beginWasLast = false;
});

$('a:not(a[href="#begin"])').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(beginWasLast){
        console.log( e.target.href );
    }
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/6zKDF/)

I added in the `e.preventDefault();` calls so that the page didn't reload when the links were clicked.

Comment: well I've wrote a little hack for this... I've just setTimeout for 500 ms to trigger .hide() event, and the "click" event executes itself before the setTimeout is complete, so I get blur for my case working perfectly! thanks for your tips though!

Comment: @Zlatan: What has timeout and hide got to do with your question? You mention nothing about them!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to know which element got the focus from the `blur` event itself. You would need to add a click event to get that, like this:

```
$('a[href="#begin"]')
    .blur(function(e) {
        console.log( e.target.href ); // previous link href
    });
    .click(function(e) {
        console.log( e.target.href ); // current link href
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

An other possible way could be:
[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8SpxW/)

```
$('a[href="#begin"]').blur(function(e) {
  setTimeout(function(){console.log( $(document.activeElement).attr('href') );},0); 
});
```