# blur event: get the element clicked from inside the blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible  to get the dom element that was clicked from the blur event.

```
myTxtBox.blur(function (e) { 

var myTxtBoxClass =   e.target.className
var getClassOfElementclicked ==  //get the class of clicked element

 });
```

Comment: Yes,

Check here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544554/get-the-clicked-object-that-triggered-jquery-blur-event

Comment: +1 on the reference, only thing I'll add is avoid global variables like that. try to scope it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use .click(function(){}); to get clicked object. Then you can set it to blur. Right now it is unclear what initiates the blur event in the first place.

If you want to see which object that is currently "blurring" is clicked, you could assign a class to the objects when they blur and assign click event to this class.

Answer (score 0):

`blur` can be called for more than just clicking away from a control--the user could have tabbed away. If all you're interested in is the target of a `click` event, then you can register a handler for clicks.

However, if you're more interested in the elements that gain & lose focus in close proximity to one another (they are two separate events, so you can't really consider a `blur` to have a "newly-focused target" attribute, you can use something like this:

```
$('input').blur(function (e) {
    console.log('lost focus: ', e.target);
});
$('input').focus(function (e) {
    console.log('gained focus: ', e.target);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/QUDED/

Also, be sure to see the discussion of `blur()` in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/blur/): the event doesn't bubble in IE, so depending on your use case, you may wish to use the `focusout` event instead.

Comment: thanks but here is my real problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270504/div-is-not-getting-focus-in-time-blur-fires-before-the-focus-out  I was trying to break it down