# Prevent loss of focus unless hovering over a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a textarea `#content` and an input textbox `#name`. Once the user has clicked on `#content`, I want to prevent him from loosing focus of that textarea, unless he is clicking on `#name`.

I've tried the following:

```
// Prevent loss of focus for textarea
$("#content").on("blur", function(event) {
    $('#name').mouseover(function() {
       return true;
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    this.focus();
    return false;
});
```

It works just fine to prevent loss of focus of an element. But my idea of checking if he's hovering `#name` and returning just doesn't work.

Comment: `$("#name").mouseover(function(){})` doesn't test whether a hover is occurring at that moment, it binds a mouseover handler that will be executed later _if_ a hover occurs later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stole the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544554/get-the-clicked-object-that-triggered-jquery-blur-event) to get the element that triggered the `blur`.

```
var clicky;

$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    // The latest element clicked
    clicky = $(e.target);
});

$("#content").on("blur", function(event) {
    if (clicky.attr('id') == 'name') {
        return true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    this.focus();
    return false;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUC7f/)

Comment: This doesn't work, because clicking isn't the only way to change focus.

Comment: @nnnnnn, but OP only care about when `#name` is clicked?

Comment: With this code, if you click on the name element _first_ you can then use the tab key to move focus around to any other elements, including to the textarea and then to something other than the name element.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var id;
   $('#content').on('blur',function(){
       $(":input").focus(function(){
          id = this.id;
          if(id != 'username' && id != 'content'){ // sorry, changed your id from name to username. 
              $('#content').focus();   
              }
           });       
      });
  });
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ugx3S/

Comment: This assigns additional focus handlers to all inputs every time `#content` loses focus.